# Why does only one child window show?(x11)

Tags: visibility, xlib, x11

I have a small piece of code where I create 4 non overlapping sets(Top/Bottom Left/Right) of 3 windows(1 parent window 1 child window almost as large as the parent window and 1 small button window). Then I map each window.

Yet only in the top left quadrant(which is created first) do the child windows show. I've tried not creating the top left windows and the quadrant created first in that case doesn't show child windows. I've tried switching the order of window mapping and it doesn't make a difference. The windows exist according to xwininfo and I don't get any X errors.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: It is impossible to say anything meaningful without looking at the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In case anybody else comes across similar problems)
I made a mistake in putting absolute coordinates for child windows where they really are
relative to their parent window in xlib(which makes a lot of sense).
 So of course only the top window would show a a child window(since thats the only one where they could overlap.